# Android Service questions about bind/unbind?

Tags: android, service, bind, unbind

The original bind/unbind service can be called by client using `bindService()`/`unbindService()`.

My question is how to unbind service in service side, not called `unbindService()` by client, probably I should call it `unbindClient`.

I think the service should know which clients are bound to it, so is there any way to tell the service to unbind a specific client?

Because i only write the service, and i do't know if the client called `unbindService()` correctly,so i have this question..

Comment: There might be something you can do to restructure your classes. Why do you need to know which client disconnected from the service?

Comment: like normal c/s program,i want to do some underlying recycle work when a client disconnected,do you have any better idea?

Comment: Can you call it from the `Activity` that disconnected from the `Service` instead? There's an `onDestroy()` method for activities, or `onPause()` or `onStop()`. You might be able to put it there.

Answer (score 1):

A service cannot unbind itself.  You can make a started service *stop* itself with `stopSelf()` though.

The OS keeps track of all the binding and unbinding behind the scenes.  You don't have to worry about object recycling, Android does it for you.

Comment: If you think the answer is misleading.  Please point out what do you think is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to client code -

You can call `startService()` from the client - which will start the service (and not end the `Service` on exiting the `Activity` - since only `stopService()` will close it).

And also, Client could call `bindService()` - if they want to perform `Activity`-`Service` interaction.

On exiting/unbinding the client, the service will still run since `startService()` was called - `Service` can perform other operations and then call `stopService()` which will destroy itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merely limit the functionality that you service returns once it is started and bindService() is called.You could register a client and unregister when you are done with the service.That way binding your service will not have any impact.This I picked from the [Remote Messenger Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#RemoteMessengerServiceSample) example  in the android website